# Extracting Folder Structure from XML in .net4.0 C #

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

Thanks guys for previous answers...hey actually I want to extract a list of files and folders from a XML doc....This is my XML doc looks like...

```
   <TrebuchetWorkspaceTemplate>
     <InputDocument>
        <BusinessDocument>
          <BusinessRequirement />
          <ProcessModel />
        </BusinessDocument>
        <FunctionalDocuments />
        <UseCases />
        <Agile />
    </InputDocument>
    <Miscellaneous />
```

here trebuschet had 2 sub foldes inputdoc and miscell .....inpout doc has further 5 folders and in which business doc has 2 subfolders.....

Now I want to extract the content and make a folder structure out of it(hope u getting it).....and add to Capability element and return it....however i am getting a wrong folder structure in which instead of expected 6 there are 18 children.....(will give u it if u want)...this is my program....

```
    public Capability Parse(XElement xElem)
    {
     Capability capParent = newCapability();                                           

     capParent.Name =xElem.Name.LocalName;                               

      if (xElem.HasElements)
        {

            foreach (XElement xChild in xElem.Descendants())
            {
                Capability capChild = Parse(xChild);
                capParent.Children.Add(capChild);
            }
        }
        return capParent;
    }
```

could anyone please help me in getting the code right...?

Comment: You haven't given us *any* indication of how you'd want to map your original XML (which is incomplete and unhelpfully indented) onto objects. It's very hard to help you with the question in its current form. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: could you please give me a code where there is a similar kind of task performed..?

Comment: Similar to what? You still haven't explained exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765) instead of [`.Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635). `.Descendants()` gives you all the children, and grandchildren, and so on. `.Elements()` gives you just the direct children.